# Why doesn't this gradient work in Safari?

Tags: css

This works in Firefox, but for some reason the gradient doesn't apply in Safari. Any ideas?

```
#footer .buttons .btn {
    width: 110px;
    height: 61px;
    background: #BAE9FF;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BAE9FF 0%, #2081D6 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, colorstop(0%,#BAE9FF), colorstop(100%,#2081D6));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change `colorstop` to `color-stop` inside `-webkit-gradient`.

How on earth did you manage to remove those hyphens?

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/Hnjxs/)

---

I recommend you use this site to generate your CSS3, that way you can't go wrong:

http://css3generator.com/

Comment: FFS. I can't believe it was something like that. That site is very useful, I will certainly use it.

Answer (score 2):

`colorstop` should be `color-stop` I think:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#BAE9FF), color-stop(100%,#2081D6));
```